# UIAlertView cuts off last row of message

Tags: objective-c, xcode, alert

I would like to show an alert using a `UIAlertView` with a lot of text.

When I show this alert in the iOS simulator running iOS 4.2 it covers the navigation bar and the tab bar, however when I run the app on my iPhone running iOS 3.1.3 the alert message doesn't cover the navigation and tab bar. Furthermore, my "Okay" button cuts off the last part of the text of the `UIAlertView`.

How can I prevent the last line of text in the `UIAlertView` from being cut off on my iPhone running iOS 3.1.3 as it is on the simulator running iOS 4.2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of depending on UIAlertView (which isn't meant for displaying an e-book's worth of long form text), you should create your own UIAlertView-like modal dialog with a scrollable text view so you can display everything you want the user to see.

Comment: Thanks for answer. "ok" button cover only my last row, in simulater it shows correct not cover my last row, if iphone will show as simulator will be fine. How can I do ?

Comment: maybe you could shorten the amount of text you are displaying by a line?  :-)

Comment: how can I set UIAlertView child of main window???             [mainwindow addSubview:alertView] as this ????

Comment: I'm pretty sure UIAlertViews will turn into scrollable text boxes if you have too much text, or you can subclass it to do that.